# How to rename grails plugins?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

According to [the documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/package-plugin.html), if I have a plugin descriptor called `WidgetGrailsPlugin.groovy`, then running `package-plugin` will produce a plugin called `grails-widget-<version>.zip`.

Is there any way to override this? Ideally I just want it to generate a plugin called `widget-<version>.zip`.

And if not, is there any harm in me just renaming (manually) the plugin to be what I want? Or does Grails require the `grails-` prefix (if so, why and in what way(s))?

Comment: Why do you care what the zip file name is?

Comment: @Burt Beckwith I'm shocked this is your response! Is the zip file not the plugin itself? If so I would hope that you are free to name your own plugin whatever you like! I take it from your response that this is not possible? Why would Grails box developers in like that???

Answer (score 0):

Burt makes a good point, why does it matter?

However, that said it doesn't matter if the zip file contains grails- in the file name or not. It can be named whatever you want really, but keep in mind you are breaking a Grails convention by doing that and going against the community at large.

The convention for the name of the zip file is determined by the PluginPackager ([source on github](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/3802127cd6a399556589c1844b43dfb77229c74d/grails-core/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/publishing/PluginPackager.groovy)) and can't be customized. So it's up to you to either manually rename the file or write your own Gant script that will package the plugin and rename it.

Good luck, and maybe think twice about breaking convention unless you have a very specific reason to do so.